# Html парсер под ios

Tags: парсер, ios, iphone, синтаксический-анализ

Вот скачал [данный парсер](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios), начал тестировать, и всё бы хорошо, но когда нажимаю на новость, то во view detail на весь экран горит надпись `<Tutorial: 0x7b8...>`, причём вторая часть надписи меняется в зависимости от новости.

В чём может быть косяк (просто, судя по комментариям, у всех всё работает)? Использую sdk 8.1.

Comment: @Bimawa ну хотелось бы, конечно, чтобы и на 5 приложение пошло, вот, например, предыдущая версия приложения пошла и на iphone 4s и на 5s (5s последняя прошивка), но там всё отражалось через webview, сейчас вот нужно сделать через парсер, по этому и спрашиваю: делать на последней версии xcode проект с нуля или можно этот взять за основу (но тогда нужно, чтобы он на последней прошивке пошёл)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> в чём может быть косяк (просто, судя по комментариям, у всех всё работает)

В отсутсвии косяка. Без косяков проги вообще не работают.

**UPD**
Отрефакторил чутка, найдите отличия: [вот мой вариант](http://cl.ly/3R270x0H2O1w).

**UPD1**

Изучив работу классов, у меня вызвало подозрения строка:

```
self.detailDescriptionLabel.text = [self.detailItem description];
```

так как свойство `description` стандартное и ни чего кроме, как область памяти по умолчанию особо то и не показывает. Так как само совойство `self.detailItem` имеет тип id,

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) id detailItem;
```

то есть чуть ли не корневой объект объектов, вызвало подозрения: "А что автор хотел вообще тут ввывести?". Ну пошел смотреть класс `MasterViewController` и увидел что он кастит эти данные, которые затем отправляет в `DetailViewController`, в `NSDate` O_o:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (!self.detailViewController) {
        self.detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    }
    NSDate *object = [_objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; // Внимание сюда
    self.detailViewController.detailItem = object;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Это вызвало недоумения еще больше, и я пошел искать:"Откудаж там берется такой много функциональный объект?", дошел до инициализации массива `_object` и нашел это:

```
NSMutableArray *newTutorials = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    for (TFHppleElement *element in tutorialsNodes) {
        // 5
       Tutorial *tutorial = [[Tutorial alloc] init];// Внимание сюда
        [newTutorials addObject:tutorial];

        // 6
        tutorial.title = [[element firstChild] content];

        // 7
        tutorial.url = [element objectForKey:@"href"];
    }

    // 8
    _objects = newTutorials;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
```

Ну, а дальше все стало ясно, и в общем дальше сами... работа время деньги... сами понимаете. ;)

Comment: @Bimawa спасибо большое, но вот отличия найти не могу, подскажите что изменили? И подскажите, не могу найти где меняется тот html который выводится в detail view (просто вы вывели заголовок а мне нужно тело страницы - текст)

Comment: Ок раз результат устроил обновил ответ

Comment: @Bimawa ну как вам сказать))) я понял что во detailwievcotr. нужно заменить строчку
 
    self.detailDescriptionLabel.text = self.detailItem.title;

на какую то ф-цию, но вот написать такую ф-цию не могу, так что если подскажите, буду благодарен, если нет, то буду пробовать сам

Comment: @Гошка Тарасов тут как бы проблемма в том что надо знать матчасть, так как простая замена данной строчки ни чего не изменит. Во-вторых, нужно понимать что вы хотите получить на выходе, и каким боком html парсер вообще тут стоит? В-третьих, ну а тут от предыдущих ответов зависит и это уходит за грани топика.

Comment: @Bimawa и на том спасибо, последний дурацкий вопрос, если этот проект запущу на 6 iphone он пойдёт без проблем? (просто я работаю в последнем xcode) там несколько другая структура, вот и спрашиваю не пропадут ли мою труды?

Comment: @Гошка Тарасов, от iPhone зависит форм фактор это каснется верстки. Логика зависит от весрии операционной системы, там могут быть танцы, так как версия SDK достаточно координально меняется, чтоб причинить головную боль.

Comment: @Bimawa т.е. логичнее сразу на новую sdk пытаться ставить этот парсер?

Comment: @Гошка Тарасов это зависит от ТЗ. Если вы не собираетесь поддерживать юзеров на ios7, то можете спокойно кодить под ios8